# Combine two rasters sets using weighted geometric mean

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, combine

#### My question is:

How can I combine two to four raster layers using weighted geometric mean?

I am using ArcMap 10.3. I want to use the weighted geometric mean since it nicely reflects a situation when a shortage in one element limits the result and cannot be compensated by other elements.
The raster layers all have the same cell size, same extent and come as .tiff files, though converting them wouldn't be a problem.